# static array of pointers vs non static array of pointers

Tags: c, dos, 16-bit

What are the differences between adding and not adding the `static` keyword in the following array of pointers declaration.

```
static char *list[MAX] = {
        "Katrina",
        "Nigel",
        "Alistair",
        "Francesca",
        "Gustav"
    };
```

this declaration is located inside the `main` function

Answer (score 1):

With `static` the array of pointers will have static storage duration and without it will have automatic storage duration. In both cases the string literals pointed by the pointer elements of the array will have static storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `list` is declared in the main function, it will be allocated on the stack unless the `static` keyword is used. In either case, the string literals will not be allocated on the stack.